# how to use anync await in mongoose virtuals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have this code where I am trying to set the plain password to encrypted password with mongoose virtual and mongoose methods
this is my code

```
UserSchema.virtual("password")
  .set(async function (password) {
    this.encry_password = this.returnSecurePassword(password)
  })
  .get(function () {
    return this.encry_password;
  });

UserSchema.methods = {
  returnSecurePassword: async function (password) {
    const saltRounds = 10
    await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function await(err, hash) {
      console.log(hash);
      return hash;
    });
  },
};
```

but whenever I run this it says promise pending

Comment: Is `returnSecurePassword` a promise? If so, you miss the `await`. Also, `function await(err, hash)` is not correct. You have to remove the `await`.

Comment: @Jérôme yes it is promise can you explain me further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returnSecurePassword method is async means, it will return a promise.
To solve this use the returnSecurePassword with `await` like
`this.encry_password = await this.returnSecurePassword(password)`

And secondly, if you persist in using bcrypt.hash() then you should use Promise, something like this

```
UserSchema.methods = {
  returnSecurePassword: async function (password) {
    const saltRounds = 10
    const hash = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(hash);
      });
      return hash;
  })
};
```

Or take usage of bcrypt.hashSync, then is no need for async/await
`this.encry_password = this.returnSecurePassword(password)` stays as it is

```
UserSchema.methods = {
  returnSecurePassword: function (password) {
    const saltRounds = 10
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds)
  },
};
```